# Changing a Switch in one room but lights in other rooms go out

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch

[image]

So there are 2 sets of wires coming in on the right (black, white ground) and 1 set of wires going out to the left (black, black), which seem to connect to the next room.

When I change the switch, I ran the 2 right black wires to the dimmer switch. It works for that light, but the lights in the rooms to the left will no longer turn on. I even put back on the old switch (not a dimmer, just on/off) the same way it was and the lights in the other rooms will no longer turn on.

I am unsure what is going on here or how to get the lights in the other room to turn back on after the switch is replaced. Could really use some help.

Comment: What is that white wire doing in the bare ground bundle, and where does that cloth/string-wrapped wire in the top-left of your photo go to?

Comment: The white wire was originally attached to the bare ground bundle. After some recent research I realize that is incorrect . However, if I take it all apart I am unsure how to rewire it properly. The cloth wrapped wire to the top left appears to run to a light in the room behind this room. For example, I can attach my dimmer switch red/white wire to the unpaired black wire to control the other room light.